# K-Means Clustering in R programming

Tags: r, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, visualization, k-means

I am trying to write a program using K-Means clustering for the given dataset.

```
Package Name: cluster.datasets
install.packages("cluster.datasets")
library(cluster.datasets)
data(anime)
anime
data(mammal.dentition)
```

How can I find optimal number of clusters in the above dataset using Elbow Method to finally apply K-means? Then somehow I also have to do visualization for K-Means Clustering.

Comment: There is no dataset anime in in cluster.datasets

Comment: Have you read `?kmeans` and the **wealth of information on this topic here and elsewhere**?

Answer (score 1):

(Don't want to give you all details for your homework ;) The missing pieces you need to fill-in yourself)

Actually the calculation is fairly easy. K-means provides you the sum of squared errors. You just need to sum these up

```
swss <- sapply(1:10,
               function(x){
                 cl <-kmeans(mammal.dentition[2:length(mammal.dentition)],x)
                 sum(cl$withinss)
               })
```

This results in the plot
[image]

This results in 3 clusters.

To visualise the results you can use PCA or TSNE to generate a 2-dimensional embedding of your data.

If I run TSNE and color the dataset by cluster membership I get:

[image]